# What is a Digital Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sup>This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) and [What is a Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee).</sup>

---

Digital Words™ are words that follow a certain rule. If a word follows this rule, it is a Digital Word™.

| Digital Words™ | Not Digital Words™ |
| --- | --- |
| DAUGHTER | SON |
| PEAR | MANGO |
| RAPIER | CUTLASS |
| FIVE | FOUR |
| EGYPT | CHINA |
| BIRDWATCHES | STARGAZES |
| TAX | TACKS |
| HUBCAP | KNEECAP |
| VERTEBRATE | INVERTEBRATE |
| PEPSI | COKE |
| TEST | QUIZ |
| REGGAE | COUNTRY |
| DEDUCE | EVALUATE |
| RED | BLUE |
| EXPIRE | EMPIRE |
| RIGHT | WRONG |

---

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Digital Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples of Digital Words™, many more exist.

CSV version:

```
Digital Words™,Not Digital Words™
DAUGHTER,SON 
PEAR,MANGO  
RAPIER,CUTLASS
FIVE,FOUR 
EGYPT,CHINA  
BIRDWATCHES,STARGAZES  
TAX,TACKS 
HUBCAP,KNEECAP 
VERTEBRATE,INVERTEBRATE  
PEPSI,COKE 
TEST,QUIZ 
REGGAE,COUNTRY 
DEDUCE,EVALUATE 
RED,BLUE  
EXPIRE,EMPIRE  
RIGHT,WRONG
```

---

**What makes a word a Digital Word™?**

Comment: Are you sure KISS is a digital word? If not, I've found *something*.

Comment: I found the same thing, and I have reason to believe @Glorfindel is correct.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A digital word

> has only letters whose order number, when written in hexadecimal, has no letters.

This doesn’t work for the the final digital word “KISS”, but the logic fits the title too well for that not to be a glitch in the question.

In particular,

> the letters that make a word “non-digital” are
>  **J, K, L, M, N, O** (letters 10-15, or 0xA to 0xF) and **Z** (letter 26, or 0x1A)